# Gameobject with Canvas child (Unwanted inspector behavior)

Tags: unity

When I try to focus (by double clicking or pressing f) on gameobjects in my scene which have a Canvas as a child, the scene view zooms out to show the Canvas. I would like to be able to see the gameobjects themselves when focusing on them. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If the canvas is a screen space or camera overlay UI, un-child them from the parent object entirely or create a new parent and place the old parent and canvas as siblings under the new parent.

If it's a world space UI, you likely don't have much choice (unless the moving it to a common parent works for your situation), because you probably need it where it is to inherit the parent's transform. But in that instance the UI should likely be smaller than a screen space UI, so make sure you have it scaled appropriately for your scene.